# increasing channels of morpher modifier with maxscript?

Tags: maxscript

I am working now on rigging a face character  and therefore I am made for that more than 100 morphers, but the morpher modifier does not add more than 100, so please answer me, how can i increase channels of morpher modifier in maxscripts?

Answer (score 0):

Starting in 3ds Max 2017, a Morpher modifier may have more than the default 100 channels.  Adding additional channels is possible from the UI or MaxScript.

From the UI, scroll to the last set of channels 91-100, click any of the "-empty-" buttons, then click "Capture Current State" or "Pick Object from Scene".  Now you can scroll further, and the total is 200 channels.  You can repeat this as many times as needed.

From MaxScript, create a new morpher channel using `WM3_MC_BuildFromNode()`, passing the modifier, the desired channel number, and an appropriate object; either the morph object itself or another object with identical topology.  If the channel number is greater than 100, then the number of available channels is increased accordingly.

Example:

```
s = sphere()
m = Morpher()
addmodifier s m
WM3_MC_BuildFromNode m 120 s  -- capture current state to morph channel 120
```

Note that other MaxScript exposure functions for the Morpher modifier also have names starting with "WM3".  To list them, enter the following into the MaxScript Listener:

```
help "wm3"
```